# How can I show the list of google docs to the user on a flex air application?

Tags: apache-flex, air, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am working on a small Flex Air application and I need to give the user the ability to see a list with his Google docs and do a few more things with them. I am wondering, what are the options I have to accomplish this?

Thanks a lot!

-David.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Documents List API to retrieve the list of docs for the user:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#getting_a_list_of_documents_and_files

There's is no native Flex client library (and I don't know much about Flex), but you should be able to send HTTP requests to implement the API protocol. For instance, to retrieve the list of documents for the user, you have to send an authorized GET request to https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full.

For more details about the authorization mechanisms, check the relevant section in the docs: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#authorizing_requests